# Where to use the dark gray 1x4 flat pieces in Lego Hidden Side Ghost Train Express 70424

Tags: sets, instructions

I got two out of three pieces left of these after finished the building and I am now asking where they are supposed to be?

[image: 4211001]

The instructions can be viewed here if anyone cares to help and search.
https://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/70424/Ghost_Train_Express

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 115 needs all three 1 x 4 Plates in Dark Bluish Gray [BL]/Dark Stone Grey [TLG].

[image]

You've probably skipped sub-step 7 of step 115, where both parts need to be added:

[image]

Comment: Very helpful, much obliged!